# Make ipyrad use cuda-enabled NVidia card on Ubuntu

Tags: python, assembly, genotyping, radseq

I want to use ipyrad on a new Ubuntu machine that has an NVidia Quadro K2000 card with 384 cores. One [can](http://ipyrad.readthedocs.io/HPC_script.html) configure ipyrad to run on a linux cluster.   Do I have any options to get ipyrad to access these cores?

I'm assuming that I will be able to install cuda drivers on the machine. If ipyrad can't be made to do this, is there another way to do de novo assembly of GBS data that will take advantage of this resource?

Comment: GPU core ≠ CPU core. The two aren’t interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to get [CUDA Python](https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-python) set up on your system and likely modify ipyrad to actually use it (for example, by incorporating [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/)). So while this is possible, it will require significant effort on your part. In general, there are very few bioinformatics tools that support GPUs.